# Conversion from PPBV to PPBM

Tags: particle-physics, density, unit-conversion

What is the conversion between PPBV and PPBM?

I have a database that includes values of Parts-per-billion-by-volume (PPBV) as a function of altitude. I've been asked to convert this to "parts-per-billion-meter" (PPBM). I've never used this unit before, and I'm having trouble finding it in the literature.

Can I simply integrate a curve of PPBV to get PPBM?